# How do Flutter notification frameworks react to data changes?

Tags: flutter, notifications

This is a question about the notification/ event architecture in Flutter packages.

Suppose I have a banking application with many pages like account summary, deposits, credit score etc.

When the User object changes, that is, a new user logs in, obviously all these pages will have to be reconstructed. I can either use Streams, Blocs or a Notification framework like Riverpod to notify every page about the state change.

Now I have a question: will all the pages be rebuilt when the notification arrives? There will be only one active page at a time, so building all the other pages seems to be wasteful. Some users may never even check their credit rating page.

Or, is there a store and forward mechanism to defer the notification unless a page becomes active? In this case, how do they manage multiple successive versions of data? Different widgets may end up receiving different versions of the data. Please point me to some documentation.